# Scope Elasticsearch Results to Specific Ids

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-rails

I have a question about the Elasticsearch DSL.

I would like to do a full text search, but scope the searchable records to a specific array of database ids.

In SQL world, it would be the functional equivalent of `WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

I've been researching, but I find the Elasticsearch query DSL documentation a little cryptic and devoid of useful examples. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example query which might work for you. This assumes that the `_all` field is enabled on your index (which is the default). It will do a full text search across all the fields in your index. Additionally, with the added `ids` filter, the query will exclude any document whose id is not in the given array.

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "match": {
        "_all": "your search text"
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "ids": {
        "values": ["1","2","3","4"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Brooke! That is exactly what I was looking for. The nuances of syntax are very very helpful. Much gratitude.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty powerful. I'm definitely loving it, just need a little help navigating the syntax. Thanks again!

Comment: There is definitely a learning curve, coming from a SQL background. When you get a chance, I highly recommend going through the guide. It is invaluable, and much easier to follow than just the documentation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html

Answer (score 3):

As discussed by Ali Beyad, ids field in the query can do that for you. Just to complement his answer, I am giving an working example. In case anyone in the future needs it.

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field": "your query"
          }
        },
        {
          "ids" : {
            "values" : ["0aRM6ngBFlDmSSLpu_J4", "0qRM6ngBFlDmSSLpu_J4"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [es doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html), you can

> Returns documents based on their IDs.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids" : {
      "values" : ["1", "4", "100"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bool query that contains an Ids query in a MUST clause:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-ids-query.html

By using a MUST clause in a bool query, your search will be further limited by the Ids you specify.  I'm assuming here by Ids you mean the _id value for your documents.

Comment: Ali Beyad, thanks for the reply! Would you be so kind as to provide a full example of what the query json would look like? I'm wanting to do a full text search across all indexed fields and include the MUST clause, but everything I have tried results in syntax errors and I cannot find a good written example anywhere.

Comment: @mindtonic : so you want both the full-text search and the id search in the same request ?

Comment: I would also like to see a query example. Adding it to a condition within a bool should doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. The [`ids` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html):

```json
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": ["1, 2, 3"]
    }
  }
}
```

or

2. The [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

```json
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "yourNonPrimaryIdField": ["1", "2","3"]
    }
  }
}
```

The `ids` query targets the document's [internal `_id` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) (= the primary ID). But it often happens that documents contain secondary (and more) IDs which you'd target thru the `terms` query.

*Note that if your secondary IDs contain uppercase chars and you don't set their field's [mapping to `keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), they'll be normalized (and lowercased) and the terms query will appear broken because it only works with exact matches. More on this here: [Only getting results when elasticsearch is case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62558571/only-getting-results-when-elasticsearch-is-case-sensitive/62559379#62559379.)*

Answer (score 0):

With elasticaBundle symfony 5.2

```
    $query = new Query();
    $IdsQuery = new Query\Ids();
    $IdsQuery->setIds($id);
    $query->setQuery($IdsQuery);
    $this->finder->find($query, $limit);
```