# Only getting results when elasticsearch is case sensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently have a problem with my multi match search in ES.
Its simple like that: If I'm searching for the City "Sachsen", I'm getting results.
If I'm searching for "sachsen" (lowercase), I'm getting no results.

how to avoid this?

**QUERY with no results**

```
{
"match" : {
    "City" : {
        "query" : "sachsen"
    }
}
```

My analyzer is analyzer_keyword. Should I have anything add ?

**MAPPING**

```
City: {
type: "string",
analyzer: "analyzer_keyword"
}
```

Comment: Can you show how your `analyzer_keyword` analyzer is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `analyzer_keyword` analyzer is most probably of type `keyword` which means you can only perform **exact** matches on it.

---

It's standard practice to apply multiple ["variants" of a field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html), one of which is going to match lowercase, possibly ascii-tokenized characters (think `München` -> `munchen`) and one which will not be tokenized in any way (this is what you have in your `analyzer_keyword`).

Since you intend to search the lowercase version of `Sachsen`, your mapping could look something like

```json
PUT sachsen
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "City": {
        "type": "keyword",             <----

        "fields": {
          "standard": {
            "type": "text",           
            "analyzer": "standard"     <----
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After indexing a doc

```json
POST sachsen/_doc
{
  "City": "Sachsen"
}
```

The following will work for exact matches:

```json
GET sachsen/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "City": "Sachsen"
    }
  }
}
```

and this for lowercase

```json
GET sachsen/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "City.standard": "sachsen"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm using the default, [`standard`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#_definition_5) analyzer here but you can choose any one you deem appropriate.